# "Don't give me with the scruples!"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dialects

In *[The Fortune Cookie (1966)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fortune_Cookie)* Walter Matthau's character, a cunning lawyer, says:

> What's the matter? You feel sorry for insurance companies? They got so much money they don't know what to do with it. They've run out of storage space--they have to microfilm it. What's a quarter of a million to them? They take it out of petty cash. So don't give me with the scruples.

"Don't give me with the scruples!" sounds very peculiar to my ear, syntactically. People say "I have no scruples against doing that." But "Don't give me with" is a curious construct, so is "Don't give me with the scruples." Walter Matthau had a very typical New York accent and way of speaking. I wonder if this is his idiolect or something typical of (dated?) NY dialect?

Edit: Jack Lemmon's character later in the same movie says something similar: "Don't give me with that torch."

Comment: It's slang/elliptical speech.  Don't try too hard to analyze the syntax.

Comment: It's absolutely New York Jewish/Yiddish dialect. Make with, give me with, etc.

Comment: Stop with the complaining already!

Comment: I'm BrE, not AmE, so maybe it's not up to me to have an opinion on "valid" variations on an idiomatic theme in NYC. But so far as I'm concerned, the cited example is effectively a "malapropism" (not uncommon when screenwriters are trying to reflect colloquial speech outside their own register). The idiomatic standard is *[don't] **make with the** [un]desirable thing*, not *don't **give me with** [the undesirable thing]*.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is a parallel to "*make with the*", which is slang for "*Produce, Perform*".

> **make with**
>
> slang: PRODUCE, PERFORM —usually used with ***the***
>
> Straighten up and walk … make with the feet
>
> [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make)

Another example "*make with the music*" = "*Start the music*"

Hence "*don't give with the scruples*" = "*don't express your moral doubts to me*".

Comment: [*If you don't **make with the sex** exactly when I want it {you'll be punished}*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WS-pcqTkeRoC&pg=PT175&dq=%22don%27t+make+with+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBzJPKp4fsAhVEUcAKHS10D3UQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22don't%20make%20with%20the%22&f=false) = *I require sex on demand.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "If you don't make with the sex exactly when I want it {you'll be punished}" I love it when you talk dirty, and especially when you make with the curly brackets.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Many Thanks to you for your editing, Heidless Soul. I try to achieve your excellent formatting but still seem to fall short too often.

Answer (score -2):

I think it could be simply idiosyncratic speech  modelled on "Don't give me that scruples nonsense/trash/crap/…!".